# Codenameone Migrating Legacy Applications to CSS II

Tags: codenameone

I am using Netbeans. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I'll detail what I've done in sections within the attached image:

Rename theme.res to theme_legacy.res
Delete indicated file and folders.
In the designer create the constant "theme" and save file.
Rename resource file in main class and save file.
Activate CSS file and save.
In section 6 it shows the incomplete CSS file. After executing the project another "theme" is created as shown in section 7.
[image]

I appreciate your comments.

Comment: You did everything right. CSS works and creates a new theme resource file. In the code you're still loading the theme from the designer though... So if you change it to load from CSS that would work. Do you want to inherit the old theme in the CSS? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Do you want to inherit the old theme in the CSS?    YES... please

Answer (score 0):

To do a "slow migration" just do the following:

- Remove the `includeNativeBool` constant from the CSS - this means we inherit the native theme instead of the old theme (which I assume already inherits the native theme). You can only inherit one theme...
- In the code load the legacy theme just like you do right now
- Layer the CSS on top by adding the following line:
  `theme = UIManager.initNamedTheme("/theme", "Theme");`

Once you do that the theme will include both the legacy code and the new stuff. This is from the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html) "Theme Layering" section.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, my goal is to take a "theme.res" file and convert it to "theme.css". Is there a way to do it automatically?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, my goal is to take a "theme.res" file and convert it to "theme.css". Is there a way to do it automatically?

or will they have some example code CN1 with CSS

Comment: We don't have an automatic converter. You would need to keep the designer open and copy rules from the original res file to the CSS file. Then remove the rule from the res file. The most we can do is layer the CSS on top of the resource file so you can do that migration in stages.